# Duplicate a row in JQGrid and save it to model, using mvc4 visual studio 2012

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, jqgrid

Good day, this is my first question in stackoverflow, i need to duplicate a row using JQGRID, and then, save it to the database, i am using jqgrid 4.4.4, jquery, visual studio 2012, MVC4 and SQL Server 2008 R2.
I have created a custom button, the idea was that when i click it, it duplicates the selected row and when i click on the save button, this can save the duplicated row into the database.

I have visually duplicated the row but, i dont know how to save it to the database. The save button always makes post with the oper value "edit".
anyone had done this before? Thanks for any help.

This is the code for duplicate the selectec row:

```
    newId = "new";
                        $('#' + grid2.id).jqGrid('addRowData', newId, myData, "after", selIdRow);
                        $('#' + grid2.id).jqGrid('setSelection', newId, false);
                        $('#' + grid2.id).jqGrid('editRow', newId);
                        $("#" + grid2.id + "_iledit").addClass('ui-state-disabled');
                        $("#" + grid2.id + "_ilsave").removeClass('ui-state-disabled');
                        $("#" + grid2.id + "_ilcancel").removeClass('ui-state-disabled');
```

Comment: It's important to know whether the grid have *local* data or not (which `datatype` you use). How you fill the grid with data? By the way the usage of `"new"` as new rowid is not so good. It's better to use `undefined` as `newId`. In the case jqGrid will generate new *unique* rowid automatically. I recommend you to update jqGrid 4.4.4 to more recent version of jqGrid: 4.6, 4.7 or to use recently published [free jqGrid 4.8](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid) which you can install from [nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/free-jqGrid).

Comment: Thanks, my jqgrid´s datatype is json, i fill it from an ajax call... Thanks for your comment.!